# connection re established in Service class

Tags: android, connection, wifi, android-service

I have created a `chat application`. My `Service` has a connection which I used in my application. when an incoming message arrives then it proves that `Service` class's connection with the server is alive. When my network connection has failed then the connection with the server is disconnected but the `Service` is still running.

Is there a way to ensure that my connection with the server will be alive for all time? If any network problem is found, how do I make sure it is automatically re-established within the `Service`.

Thank you.